# Modal dont show data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, spring-boot

i make app in Spring Boot and i have problem with display specyfic information on modal.
Modal show up corectly but dont show data from database about specyfic store_id

I dont know what is wrong and where i make mistake i will be glad that you can help me find it.

To inform im begginer, its app only for my usage :D Just

This is site in HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <th:block th:replace="~{fragments/formatki :: head_scripts}"></th:block>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar  -->
    <div th:replace="~{fragments/formatki :: navbar}"></div>

    <!-- Page Content  -->
    <div id="content">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-dark">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-dark d-inline-block d-lg-none ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a th:href="@{/showAddUserHasStoreForm}" class="btn btn-outline-dark"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <h1>Zawartość tabeli CHS</h1>
        <div class="table-responsive-lg">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>Lp.</th>
                    <th>Użytkownik</th>
                    <th>ID Sklepu</th>
                    <th>Przyciski funkcyjne</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr th:each="uhs : ${userHasStoreAll}">
                    <td class="lp-column" th:text="${uhs.id_uhs}">ID UHS</td>
                    <td class="content-column" th:text="${uhs.user.user_login}">Klient</td>
                    <td class="content-column" th:text="${uhs.store.id_store}">Numer sklepu</td>
                    <td class="functions-button">
                        <a th:href="@{/deleteUserHasStore/{id_uhs}(id_uhs = ${uhs.id_uhs})}" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Usuń</a>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary open-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#storeModal"
                                data-store-id="${uhs.store.id_store}">
                            Szczegóły
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Dodaj ten kod na końcu Twojej strony HTML, przed zamknięciem tagu </body> -->
<div class="modal fade" id="storeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="storeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="storeModalLabel">Informacje o sklepie</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p><strong>Numer sklepu:</strong> <span id="storeNumber"></span></p>
                <p><strong>Nazwa sklepu:</strong> <span id="storeName"></span></p>
                <p><strong>Miasto:</strong> <span id="cityName"></span></p>
                <p><strong>Ulica:</strong> <span id="streetAddress"></span></p>
                <p><strong>Numer ulicy:</strong> <span id="streetNumber"></span></p>
                <p><strong>Kod pocztowy:</strong> <span id="zipCode"></span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".open-modal", function () {
        var id_store = $(this).data("store");

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: `/storeDetails/${id_store}`,
            success: function (data) {
                // Ustawia dane o sklepie w modalu
                $("#storeNumber").text(data.store_no);
                $("#storeName").text(data.store_name);
                $("#cityName").text(data.address.city.city_name);
                $("#streetAddress").text(data.address.address_street);
                $("#streetNumber").text(data.address.address_no);
                $("#zipCode").text(data.address.city.city_zip_code);
            },
            error: function () {
                // Obsługuje błąd, jeśli nie można pobrać danych
                alert("Wystąpił błąd podczas pobierania danych o sklepie.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>

This is My Controller:
```

@Controller
public class UserHasStoreController {

```
@Autowired
public UserHasStoreService userHasStoreService;

@Autowired
public UserService userService;

@Autowired
public StoreService storeService;


@GetMapping("/storeDetails/{id_store}")
public String getStoreDetails(@PathVariable("id_store") Integer id_store, Model model) {
    Store store = storeService.getStoreByID(id_store);
    model.addAttribute("store", store);
    return "html/admins/user_has_store";
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//DISPLAY LIST OF CONNECTIONS
@GetMapping("/user_has_store")
public String getAllUserHasStore(Model model){

    model.addAttribute("userHasStoreAll", userHasStoreService.getAllUserHasStore());
    return "html/admins/user_has_store";
}
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bB59k.png
```